# Python joblib error: inner function called by function called using joblib.Parallel not found

Tags: python, linux, windows, joblib

We've encountered a strange bug which we cannot reproduce easily. The code runs successfully on a Linux machine, and a Windows machine; however it triggers an error on a second Windows machine (using the same environment as the other Windows machine)

Our current codebase is quite large, but I've tried to synthesize the situation to small code snippets that illustrate what's happening; say we have 3 files:

`myutils.py`

```
import joblib
def pmap(f, x, n_jobs):
    return joblib.Parallel(n_jobs = n_jobs)(joblib.delayed(f)(i) for i in x)
```

`mylib.py`

```
from myutils import pmap

def innerF(x):
    return x
    
def f(x):
    return innerF(x)

def runMyFunctionInParallel(x):
    return pmap(f, x, n_jobs = -4)
```

`main.py`

```
from myutils import pmap
from mylib import runMyFunctionInParallel
runMyFunctionInParallel([1,2,3,4,5])
```

We run the whole thing with

```
ipython -i main.py
```

but on this one specific machine, we get the error:

```
Exception: name 'innerF' is not defined
```

What could be causing this error? We have so far figured out that adding

```
from mylib import innerF
```

to `main.py` stops the error from happening on the one machine where it does happen.

We're running this on `Python 3.8` with `joblib 1.0.1`.

But we're still not sure exactly why it happens, and are worried about what other horrible things might be happening in the code if this one is happening, so we would like to understand the causes and how to prevent this from happening.

Comment: it may uses `pickle` to send information from one process to another - and inside pickle it can send information that it has to run function `innerF` and other process may need information about `innerF` to execute it.

Comment: @furas right, but what is still a mystery to me is why on earth it has different behaviors on two Windows machines with the same environment ...